# How do I numerically integrate a numerical solution of a differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

Suppose I have received a numerical solution to a differential equation via

```
ODE = f''[x] + f[x] - 1/f[x]^2 == 0;
sol = NDSolve[{ODE, f[0] == 1, f'[0] == 2}, f[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

Now, I would like to use the solution further

1) for numerical integration

```
g[t] := NInt[f[t] /. sol, x, {x, 0, t}]
```

So that, e.g.

```
g[5]
```

would give me a value according to the above definition of `g[t]`. The above does not work.

2) also for more complicated evaluations, such as

```
h[t] := Exp[NInt[f[t] /. sol, x, {x, 0, t}]]
```

whereby I'd like to plot the data and store into a file afterwards, i.e. something like:

```
Plot[h[t],{t, 0, 10}]
```

which does not work either.

I know these are basic operations but so far I was unable to get through the obstacles of coding the above.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/PlotTheResultsOfNDSolve.html

Comment: For 1, you can still use `NDSolve[]`: `NDSolveValue[{f''[x] + f[x] - 1/f[x]^2 == 0, f[0] == 1, f'[0] == 2, g'[x] == f[x], g[0] == 0}, {f, g}, {x, 0, 10}]`.

Answer (score 7):

There seem to be some mistakes in your approach. First I start with your ODE and then I plot the solution to check that it is sound.

```
ODE = f''[x] + f[x] - 1/f[x]^2 == 0;
sol = NDSolve[{ODE, f[0] == 1, f'[0] == 2}, f[x], {x, 0, 10}];
Plot[Evaluate[f[x] /. First@sol], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note the `Evaluate` this insures that the replacement is done once before plotting begins.

Your next line of code is

```
h[t] := Exp[NInt[f[t] /. sol, x, {x, 0, t}]]
```

What is `NInt`? This does not seem to be a Mathematica function. If you mean `NIntegrate` then this does not have the form you wrote. Do you mean

```
g[t_] := NIntegrate[Evaluate[f[x] /. First@sol], {x, 0, t}]
```

Note that I have made a pattern of `g[t_]` and removed the first `x` in the expression. Is this what you wanted?

A better approach would be to include this integration in the original ODE. So starting again we have

```
ODE1 = {f''[x] + f[x] - 1/f[x]^2 == 0, g'[x] == f[x], f[0] == 1, 
   f'[0] == 2, g[0] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[ODE1, {f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 10}];
```

The function for g is now available

```
Plot[Evaluate[g[x] /. sol], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

There are several syntax mistakes. The correct way to define the function `g[t]` is the following:

```
g[t_] := NIntegrate[f[x] /. sol[[1]], {x, 0, t}]

g[5]
(* 8.65985 *)
```

1. In order to define a function with a variable you need to use a pattern `t_` which means that every appearance of `t` at the other side of the assignation operator will be substituted by the input value to the function. Writing `g[t]` assigns an expression to this particular combination of symbols, but does not create a function.
2. Notice the correct syntax for `NIntegrate`. You can consult it in Mathematica executing `?NIntegrate` or using the help manuals.
3. I have written `/.sol[[1]]` instead of `/.sol` because `NDSolve` (and many other functions in Mathematica) returns a *list* of replacement rules, although in this case is a list with only one item. If you use `sol` you will get a list of all the results of the replacement (again, in this case a list of only one element, but a list). Of course, there's no problem with that and may be your desired result. In other case, you should avoid extracting the desired solution from the list.

Answer (score 2):

**Method I**

```
ODE = f''[x] + f[x] - 1/f[x]^2 == 0;
{f[x_]} = {f[x]} /.First@NDSolve[{ODE, f[0] == 1, f'[0] == 2}, f[x], {x, 0, 10}];
g[t_] := NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, t}];
g[5]
h[t_] := Exp[g[t]];
Plot[h[t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

**Method II**

```
ODE = f''[x] + f[x] - 1/f[x]^2 == 0;
{fsol} = NDSolveValue[{ODE, f[0] == 1, f'[0] == 2}, {f}, {x, 0, 10}];
g[t_] := NIntegrate[fsol[x], {x, 0, t}]
h[t_] := Exp[g[t]]
Plot[h[t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]